# Can You Identify These Black Studless 2x4 Brick With Train Wheels?

Tags: part-identification, trains, wheel, discontinued

I found a bunch of Pat Pend *LEGO* in a thrift shop. Among all the goodies there are two black smooth 2x4 bricks with train wheels attached to them.

Their characteristics are as followed:

- They are studless.
- Have a closed bottom.
- On one of the long sides there is a half moon like cut-out with a
  sort of flat hook thing.
- On the short sides there are detachable train wheels with ten spokes.
- The wheel axles are made of yellow brass.
- The logo on top is the old *LEGO* logo with the letter "*O*" being open.
- The logo is quite large.

Can anyone help me identify these parts?

Answer (score 5):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Hey, there *Happy Dog*!  These train pieces?

- Part #*[BB37](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=12-3)* - Train Brick 2 x 4 x 1 1/3 Sliding Block with Wheels
  Holder.
- Part #*[Wheel2A](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=wheel2a&idColor=11#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:11,%22iconly%22:0%7D)* - Wheel Spoked for Motor.

Together they appear in *[these](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=bb37&in=S)* *LEGO* sets.

See ya!

Comment: Thank you so much Rin Rio-Oki. That are the blocks!! You identified them and did that very fast. This forum is amazing. Lego made so many different parts, without a community of adult Lego lovers it would take so much time to identify every little bit of it. And I'm a beginner, but willing to learn. Thanks again. Cordially,
Happy Dog.